# Authentication Required by wifi.

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, linux-mint

I can't seem to connect to my wifi anymore. Everytime i try to connect to it, i only get this `Authentication Required` and there no password prompt at all. Like in 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzU8I.png)
Before today i was only getting this message for my new router and other routers worked fine but now i can only connect to 1 router. 
I did tried changing the value of `wifi.powersave` from 3 to 2 in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and it did work for 3-4 days but now it doesn't works at all.

I'm using linux mint 18.2 cinnamon.